# How to set up Django to run tests on PostgreSQL on Travis CI?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, travis-ci

I cannot seem to figure out how to integrate my current Django project to run tests on Travis CI. Right now I have PostgreSQL set up to run on my local machine when unit tests are run.

```
language: python
python:
  - 3.4.1
addons:
  postgresql: "9.3"
before_script:
- psql -U postgres -c "create extension postgis"
  - psql -c 'create database travis_ci_test;' -U postgres
install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - pip install coveralls
script:
  coverage run --source=calculator manage.py test
after_success:
  coveralls
```

Travis tells me:

```
$ coverage run --source=calculator manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: permission denied to create database
Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_dk5va592r6j0v', or 'no' to cancel:
```

And right now I have a hacky set-up to deal with switching between a local db and my heroku db:

```
import dj_database_url

if DEBUG:
    DATABASE_URL = 'postgres://localhost/storage'
else:
    DATABASE_URL = 'postgres://somerealurl'
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default=DATABASE_URL)}
```

Does anyone have a good way to fix my issue? It seems I need to be able to create a PostgreSQL on Travis, and then run my tests so I can get coverage. Debug will also have to be set to False, whenever the code is checked in as well.

If you could post a working Travis, DJango, and PSQL setup that would awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have done and has been successful for me is setting the DATABASE_URL as an environment variable and just using 
`DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default=DATABASE_URL)}`
in the code which will switch gracefully from local to production.

Here is a working travis config using Postgres, Django and deployed on Heroku.

https://github.com/kevgathuku/sermonbuddy/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: That link returns 404 sadly